# Print terminal command output directly into vim - macOS

Tags: macos, vim, terminal, tmux, gnu-screen

Whenever I enter a terminal command in vim (e.g., `!echo hello`), I am momentarily kicked out to view the result of that terminal command and then prompted with `Press ENTER or type command to continue`. This is a bit jarring. I would like to stay within vim and with the command output printed out at the bottom.

[image: image of getting kicked out of vim to view and respond to a terminal command that was run within vim]

I know vim `:read` will take the terminal output and actually put it into my buffer, but that is not what I am looking to do. Here is [some reading](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Append_output_of_an_external_command) if you are interested in a tangent.

It looks like when I run vim in Screen I get what I am looking for, but I am trying to get this to work with tmux and the stock Mac terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a ton of research, probably too much, I got it! It looks like vim will send commands to the terminal, which in turn defines the behavior of how the terminal commands are processed from vim. Put this into your `.vimrc` file:

```
set t_ti= t_te= " show results from terminal commands within vim!
```

From what I understand, this just makes sure to send nothing to the terminal, which yields my desired results!

[image: image of terminal command run within vim showing output in vim]

Side note: the above addition to your `.vimrc` file will also prevent the vim buffer from clearing when exiting vim (e.g., `:wq`). I am okay with this! It is kind of nice sometimes to see what you were just working on :).

Comment: For a second I thought you were setting the value of some var to be `" show results from terminal commands within vim!"`, which seemed oddly verbose for an option.

Comment: Haha, I can see how you thought that! Do you think it would be clearer to take that `vimrc` comment out?

Comment: I typically put comments on the line above, but I don't know if the average vim user considers that any more natural/readable.

Comment: For what it's worth, I put my comments on the line above because I consider it more natural and readable.